# scoping static_assert for class static member array

Tags: c++

I'd like to enforce a compile-time constraint about the length of a class static member variable array using `static_assert()`. However, the length of the variable named `lpfilter[]` is not known in the declaration in the header, and only known later in the definition. I'm uncertain how best to implement this `static_assert` so that it may see the static private array length. I have a workaround using a private scoped function to hold `static_assert`s, but is there a better way? I'm using clang 15 in C++14 mode.

```
//in header
class test
{ 
private:
    //member constants
    static const float lpfilter[];

    //feels like a workaround
    void testChecker(void);
};
```

```
//early in cpp file
const float test::lpfilter[] = {
    #include "a_single_line_lpfilter.csv"
};
```

I've made a few attempts so far. Each build error makes sense:

```
//after lpfilter[] definition in cpp file

//error: 'lpfilter' is a private member of 'test'
static_assert((sizeof(test::lpfilter)/sizeof(test::lpfilter[0])) % 2, "filter length must be even");

//error: redefinition of 'test'
class test
{
static_assert((sizeof(test::lpfilter)/sizeof(test::lpfilter[0])) % 2, "filter length must be even");
}

//error: expected unqualified-id
test::static_assert((sizeof(test::lpfilter)/sizeof(test::lpfilter[0])) % 2, "filter length must be even");

//works, but I'd prefer not to have to use a function to do this
void test::testChecker()
{
static_assert((sizeof(test::lpfilter)/sizeof(test::lpfilter[0])) % 2, "filter length must be even");
}
```

Comment: Would a [helper friend class](https://godbolt.org/z/3E9x3GhMv) bother you less than a helper function?

Comment: FWIW I'd just drop the `static_assert` into one of the constructors. If a constructor is not available I'd place it the main function that accesses the member variable (or closest to it's first logical access).

Comment: Why `lpfilter` must be private static field of `test` class? IMO simply can be some global constant in anonymous namespace in cpp file.

Comment: @MarekR: Here, that would probably be an improvement, but there are other reasons (like type completeness) to have a separate definition of what really should be a static data member.

Comment: Helper friend class does bother me less. Constructors are currently in the header, but could be moved. Type completeness is what I was going for, but static global constant in the cpp is what I would do in C, and will work.